# How to convert a whitespace string to CSV string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I convert a whitespace-delimited string to CSV string in Ruby? Is there a built-in method that could be used to achieve this?

Code:

```
@stores = current_user.channels
puts @stores
```

Current Output:

```
TMSUS TMSCA
```

Expected Output:

```
TMSUS,TMSCA
```

Comment: What is your `Code` part? It is relevant to the question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". You need to show us your effort: Where did you search and why didn't that help? Or, what did you write to solve this? As is it looks like you're asking for us to write a solution for you which is off-topic. It's better for you to show us your (failing) code and us help fix it, than for us to write something totally unrelated to your code and you try to incorporate it.

Comment: Also, the little code you showed us has no relationship to your question. "[mcve]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a CSV library in Ruby [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

```
require 'csv'
stores = 'TMSUS THSCA'
stores.split(' ').to_csv
```

Don't use `gsub` to do this. If you had a string with a comma in it, it would break your CSV. The CSV library does escaping for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael for describing this as well.

Comment: I am going to put the above-mentioned solution in one of the Rails controller. Do I need to specify the `require 'csv'` string inside the controller?

Comment: You should put it where you use the code. Knowing Rails how it loads everything, it is probably already required, but it is always nice to have these types of requirements explicit at the top of the code using it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html):

```
require 'csv'

string = 'TMSUS THSCA'

CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << string.split
end

# => "TMSUS,THSCA\n"
```

The advantage to using the CSV library is it properly escapes and quotes values which might require that.